# How to remove empty spaces in a data frame in R

Tags: r

after concatenating the variables using a *unite* function, there are rows that contain empty spaces which I need to delete in order to analyze the data.

[image]

thanks!!

I tried a *paste* function to remove directly the empty spaces when concatenating, but it didn't work.

Comment: Without seeing the full data, i'd suggest replacing the blanks with `NA` and then run `unite(..., na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: By empty spaces, do you mean the instances where there is nothing between two commas? i.e., `a,b,,,e` should be `a,b,e`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We cannot read data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: @jpsmith yes, that's what I mean

Comment: @thelatemail I tried what you said, but it didn't work

Comment: @Luise - without your data or an example, we can only guess what might have happened. The method absolutely *does* work (see diomedesdata's example code in their answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Just to start off - please don't post photos of data or code! It's much more useful to do something like `dput(head(data, 10))`.

One option might be to use `str_replace_all()`, but it could be slow if your data is really big.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df |>
  mutate(Productos = str_replace_all(Productos, ",{2,}", ",")) |> # remove double
  mutate(Productos = str_replace_all(Productos, "^,|,$", "")) # remove leading/trailing
```

That said, it looks like `unite(..., remove = FALSE, na.rm = TRUE)` is going to be better. From the [examples](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/unite.html):

```
# To remove missing values:
df %>% unite("z", x:y, na.rm = TRUE, remove = FALSE)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   z     x     y    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 "a_b" a     b    
#> 2 "a"   a     NA   
#> 3 "b"   NA    b    
#> 4 ""    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Productos = c("Cervezas,Vinos,,Tequilas,Aguardientes,,,Rones,Tabaqueria,Alimentos,Bebidas",
                               "Cervezas,,Ginebras,Tequilas,Aguardientes,,,Rones,Tabaqueria,,"))
```

You can remove two or more commas and replace them with a single comma, then remove any leading/trailing commas in base R using `gsub`:

```
gsub("^,|,$", "", gsub(",{2,}", ",",df$Productos))
```

Output:

```
[1] "Cervezas,Vinos,Tequilas,Aguardientes,Rones,Tabaqueria,Alimentos,Bebidas"
[2] "Cervezas,Ginebras,Tequilas,Aguardientes,Rones,Tabaqueria"
```